# jquery validation for multiple file input

Tags: jquery, html

```
<input type="file" name="documents[]" id="documents" multiple>
```

1.I want to apply 'required:true' validation rule for above tag.

```
$(function() {
// Initialize form validation on the registration form.
// It has the name attribute "registration"

$("form[name='register-form']").validate({
      //alert("hi");
      // Specify validation rules
    rules: {
                documents:{
                required: true,
                numofdocs: 3

                }
            }, // end of rules
    submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

2.but this code is not working.It does not apply this validation rule. and submits the form. please help.

3.same rule for single file upload is working.

Comment: IDs need to be unique. What is the selector in the rules?

Comment: "is not working" is not a very descriptive nor helpful problem description. Please specify what's not working as expected, whether you get any errors etc. Given your HTML you only use the id `documents` once, so seems to be fine. Please create a working plnkr/jsfiddle showcasing the required part of your application and also which jQuery plugins you're using.

Comment: `$("form[name='register-form']")` this line of code will return an array of objects satisfying the query. Try to iterate and inside the loop try to apply the validation rule? Just a thought...